# UITableView reloadSections does not trigger viewForFooterInSection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablefooterview

I'm trying to build an app similar to iOS native Reminders app. Where there's a list of items with header and footer. Each cell contains an `UITextView` that will dynamic change cell height when user typing. Footer view contains the same cell view, except I want it to be a footer so it would stick to the bottom view. I have cell set to dynamic height.

```
checklistTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
checklistTable.estimatedRowHeight = 60

checklistTable.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
checklistTable.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 60
```

here is the logic for update cell height while typing, this works perfectly for regular cells, but does not work for footer view. I set an breakpoint in 
viewForFooterInSection, it was never called after initial loading.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let startHeight = textView.frame.size.height
    let calcHeight = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size).height

    if startHeight != calcHeight {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()

        if cellType == .footer {
            tableView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)
        }

        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Did viewForFooterInSection ever get called initially?

Comment: The API docs only say that this method updates the cells, not the header and footers.

Comment: @nirav yes, viewForFooterInSection gets call initialize. and sometime during scrolling

Comment: Did you implement tableView:heightForFooterInSection method? It's a prerequisite.

Comment: Hi @Nirav,  Just add heightForFooterInSection and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension, still no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

Enabling & disabling animations on `UIView` & invoking `tableView?.beginUpdates()` simultaneously looks *ambiguous*.
Simply, invoking `reloadSections` should work, like:

```
if startHeight != calcHeight {

        if cellType == .footer {
            tableView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @ystack. I tried that, and it makes no difference :(

Comment: woah! Have you tried performing a simple `table.reloadData()`?

Comment: reloadData would probably redraw the footer. But I'm really looking for an elegant way of update the section footer without reload entire table, reload also cause keyboard to dismiss, which I don't want while user is typing.